# Sobrescrever método estático

Tags: c#, classes, método, polimorfismo, assinatura

Nem sei como fazer a pergunta, mais vou tentar. Tenho um método estático em uma classe pai, e eu planejava sobrescrever nas classes filhas, mas pelo o que eu estou vendo aqui, isso não e possível.

Me lembrei de um recurso que tem no Java, no qual eu nem me lembro como aplica na assinatura do método, mas eu sei que quando você vai chamar o método, você chama mais ou menos assim:

```
nomeDoMetodo(NomeDaClasse.class);
```

Acho que isso pode ser uma forma mais correta de fazer com que o método faça comportamentos diferentes.

Queria saber se tem como fazer isso no C#?

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara. Mas eu indicaria você procurar por delegates. Pode atender sua necessidade.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como é o mecanismo do Java, vou responder só a parte do C#.

O que deseja fazer não é conceitualmente correto e por isto não tem mecanismo específico para lidar com essa questão. Claro que dá para fazer com reflexão ou outros mecanismos que de alguma forma usam reflexão.

Métodos estáticos não pertencem a instância, pertencem a classe. Só método de instância podem ser sobrescritos e se ele for virtual.

Por outro lado não me parece que seja necessário. Se você quer que a classe derivada tenha um método estático com a mesma assinatura então crie este método. Não precisa fazer mais nada. Ele pode ter outra implementação ou a mesma implementação (embora neste caso seria melhor chamar o método que está servindo como base, ou nem criar este método na classe derivada).

Métodos estáticos devem ser chamados pela classe e isto por si só já impede o polimorfismo. Portanto a necessidade não faz sentido.

Comment: Estou tentando fazer um metodo que pegue todos os contatos de um arquivo, mas existem dois tipos de contatos, cada um salvando em um arquivo diferente. `public static List<Contato> Todos(Contato contato)
        {

        }`

Comment: E no lugar desse Contato contato, queria uma forma de filtrar o tipo de contato, sem ter que instanciar um objeto, por que não faria sentido

Comment: Me parece que isto não tem nada a ver com o que perguntou.

Comment: Pelo que li da sua resposta, em Java é idêntico.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado só não sei se tem alguma forma reflexiva que facilita isto que ele quer. Deve ter, em C# tem, mas é algo muito errado. Acho que ele quer fazer outra coisa, mas como vamos saber sem ele responder?

Comment: Concordo muito que reflexão neste caso não parece nada certo. Para mim faria muito mais sentido passar uma função para ser executada.

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer isso em C# `
public class Teste {

 public void ver(Class<? extends Teste> tipo) {
  
 }
}
`

Comment: Você não pode mudar a pergunta, se quer saber outra coisa faça uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Quem negativou poderia informar o que tem errado na resposta.

Comment: Mas é mesma coisa, So que dessa vez eu fui direto ao ponto, ao em vez de falar como eu chamaria, falei como é assinatura do metodo, no qual eu quero ver se é possivel no C#

Comment: A pergunta é completamente outra, pode ser que você esteja usando para a mesma coisa, mas o assunto é outro, você estava falando de método estático e agora está falando de genericidade.